# Why was this question allowed to close despite being revised?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Back in April of this year I noticed [a rather good question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/36269/were-taxes-from-senatorial-provinces-and-imperial-provinces-sent-to-their-respec), albeit worded quite vaguely. It was set to "on hold" on the 3rd of April by a number of individuals due to being "unclear" and so I offered to edit it on behalf of the author, who subsequently accepted my changes on the 7th of April.

The question was more than clear in what it was asking post edit and so why it was allowed to close is a mystery to me. Is there any way we can get it re-opened? As I understand it, it remains on hold for 5 days and it closes on the 5th, to be submitted to a "re-open" queue when edited [according to this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question). However, it appears that no one has re-opened it or, at least, has considered it worthy of re-opening.

This may well discourage the enquirer from asking in the future.

Comment: I've nominated the question for re-opening.  Let's see if that is successful.